# Uploading file to ftp from eclipse

Tags: upload, ftp, aptana, eclipse-pdt

For PHP Development i use Eclipse PDT and i'm fine with this. To speed up the deploy process i wan't to upload selected files to the appropriate directory on my FTP via eclipse.

After some googling i came across aptana. Look's fine, but unfortunatelly the upload button is disabled on nearly every file in the PHP Explorer.

Anybody has the same problem and a solution? I already configured the ftp connections and everything..

Or is there a better plugin for my usecase as i dont wan't to sync the file automatically but just wan't to upload selected files.

Thanks

Comment: If you try using the Project Explorer (not the PHP Explorer) is the upload button still disabled? When you say "nearly every file..." are there some files for which it does work?

Comment: Hey, I came across the exact some problem, and I think it has something to do with the PHP Build Path. The upload is disabled for any files that PHP Build Path excludes or includes,... no idea how to solve it though :(

Answer (score 0):

[Remove Systems Explorere](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.rse.doc.user/gettingstarted/g1installing.html) will help you.